# Problems resolving Google Cloud DNS records

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, cloud, google-cloud-dns

I have setup a wordpress instance on google cloud and pointed my domain to it by changing the DNS pointers for the domain and that works fine.
However I am trying to setup other records in the google cloud dns but they do not appear work, for example
mail.domainname.com
www.domainname.com
TXT entries for SPF and CNAME for DKIM do not show up either when I go to sites like MXtoolbox or network tools.
I have activated Google DNS API on the instance.
Is there any reason why I can't see the additional dns records?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This looks like more of a propagation of domains issue. Please note that when you make a change with your domain host, say you need to configure your MX records or set up an SPF record, it takes time for the changes to propagate to Google systems. This time is also referred to as DNS propagation. The time it takes depends on your domain host. In general, DNS changes are processed and propagated within 48 hours, but sometimes it can take up to 72 hours [1](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7514107?hl=en)

You can use the dig [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_(command)) tool to query the dns records and check/ validate their existence [3](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/)

Answer (score 0):

For DKIM on google DNS, don't enter the root domain in the TXT name field, eg: if your domain is example.com, and you're being told to enter

```
Name: my.dkim_key.example.com
Type: TXT
Value: k=rsa; p=[some long text]
```

Then in google dns, actually only enter `my.dkim_key` into the name field. If you include the whole domain including example.com, it won't propogate.  The same probably goes for the other bits of the question - CNAME, MX etc...